# How to get the horizontal position (left offset) for the colunm in monaco editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I need to convert the [lineNmber, column] coordinate to [x, y] pixel coordinate to the top-left, and I found API getTopForLineNumber and getTopForPosition to convert the lineNumber to vertical pixel coordinate, but I didn't find any API to convert column to horizontal pixel coordinate. Is there any method to convert column to horizontal pixel coordinate?

Comment: Did you end up using getOffsetForColumn? In my case it's problematic because I need the pixel offset even if lines are not visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [getOffsetForColumn](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.icodeeditor.html#getoffsetforcolumn) method to get an offset for the column from the beginning of the line.